# Prefect Shelltask fails in Supervisor

Tags: supervisord, prefect

I'm running a Prefect local agent using Supervisor.
I have two tasks in the pipeline, one shell script and a python script.
I'm able to execute the python script with no issues, but I'm unable to execute the shell task using Supervisor
(I'm able to execute both these tasks outside supervisor with no issues)

this is my supervisor config

```
[program:prefect-agent]
environment=PATH= "/home/user/venv/bin"
command =/bin/bash -c 'source activate; exec prefect agent local start'
autostart=true
autorestart=true
```

this is the prefect task

```
@task(name="task1", skip_on_upstream_skip=False, log_stdout=True)
def task1(data):
    logger = prefect.context.get("logger")
    cmd = ShellTask(
        command=f"/home/user/some_shell_script.sh",
        stream_output=True,
        log_stderr=True)
    cmd.run()
    return data
```

I understand, it has something to do with supervisor initializing bash shell, before executing the shell task.
But not sure, how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

figured it out
need to add ENV_PATH variable to the conf

```
[program:prefect-agent]
environment=PATH= "/home/user/venv/bin:%(ENV_PATH)s"
command =/bin/bash -c 'source activate; exec prefect agent local start'
autostart=true
autorestart=true
```